# Increase the speed of character smoothly in unreal

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

I'm creating a third person game and I need to increase and decrease the speed of the character smoothly. Anyone know how to do that using blueprints? your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways , through physics or simple translation in one direction etc , mostly depending on the mechanic you need for the game . The question is too broad but for the sake of practice try adding a small float with input in the forward vector of your character .(I know this is too vague but your question is not on point).I see you have used the word "smoothly" so I am thinking you need it to gradually go up or down , try using finterp , also this can be done in many ways.

If you are a beginner please refer to Unreal Tutorials on their website
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Blend Space 1D
Blendspace smooths transition between walking to running. And you can define how fast character switches from walking to running using acceleration.

[Blend Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLlvjocbXp8)

There are plenty of tutorials on blend space and is easy to setup